# bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\bin does not exist

Tags: c#, dll, .net-core, class-library, .net-4.6

I have a .Net 4.6 class library X, whose x.dll I'm referencing in my .NetCore Console application.

However, when I try to run the console application, it just throws an error saying that the dll does not exists under "bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\bin" folder. Whereas, the "bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1" does not have a bin folder.

I could see the x.dll of my class library under bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1. but no bin folder.

I tried searching this issue over the internet but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Sounds like the library was not added to the project correctly, you could potentially publish the application it will often create a folder with explicit .dll's you could try to dump there.  Also make sure it is a standard library otherwise it is not compatible with core.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you can't reference a .NET Framework dll from a .NET Core application. To get around this, you can multi-target your class library to both .Net 4.6 and .NET Standard.

Comment: That was my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check `.csproj` file of your .NET Core project.

There should be something like this

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="X" HintPath="..\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\X.dll" />
</ItemGroup>
```

You should specify a correct path to the `X.dll`.

Note that it is not the best practice to reference .NET Framework libraries from .NET Core application. You would have failures if you forgot to check that .NET Framework library is compatible with .NET Core runtime and run your application on Linux.